# SharedPref does not save changes when restarting app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

This is pretty start forward. I have a situation where I need to restart the app after clearing the shared preferences so this is what I do

```
sp.edit().clear().apply();
Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(context, IntroActivity.class);
int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
System.exit(0);
```

but it clears the sp when I just use

```
sp.edit().clear().apply();
```

and then go ahead and restart the application manually, can someone explain me how I can fix this so I can automatically restart the application without the user needing to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `commit()` instead of `apply()`.

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply())

Like the documentation states, `apply()` is asynchronous, and might not start immediately. If you call it and then immediately kill your process, it has no time to actually save the changes you made to disk.

`commit()`, on the other hand, will block the current Thread until the operation is complete, making sure `System.exit(0)` doesn't interrupt it.

Comment: I heard `commit` is bad to use and I should always use `apply` can you tell me how I can achieve this with `apply`? like is there a `waitfor` thing?

Comment: @SamzSakerz `commit()` is exactly what you want. `apply()` is for when you don't care about what happens after you call it. It's usually recommended you use it because it won't block the UI Thread and cause stuttering.

Comment: I see. This seem to have fixed the issue I decided to use `apply` because android studio kept showing me warnings for `commit` around a year ago.